# Nesting of minted and listing

Tags: minted

Can the coupling of `minted` and `listing` be wrapped into a new environment?

I'm unable to make this code work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{captionminted}{ o }
  {%
  \begin{listing}%
    \begin{minted}{cpp}%
  }%
  {%
    \end{minted}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{\caption{#1}}%
  \end{listing}%
  }


\begin{document}
\begin{captionminted}[abc]
  cout << "This is my message: "; 
  cout << str << endl; 
\end{captionminted}
\end{document}
```

Because of this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3   i
       nt i = 0;
```

Comment: Define a command that avoids to nest the two environments everywhere, one could simply write the code in `captionminted` and get the code with an optional caption

Comment: Yes, it is indeed for this reason

Comment: @siracusa `listing` is not a verbatim environment.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting `\VerbatimEnvironment`. I don't think you gain much with this approach, though: you are rather losing flexibility.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{captionminted}{ o }
 {%
  \VerbatimEnvironment\begin{listing}%
  \begin{minted}{cpp}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minted}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{\caption{#1}}%
  \end{listing}%
 }


\begin{document}

\begin{captionminted}[abc]
cout << "This is my message: ";
cout << str << endl;
\end{captionminted}

\end{document}
```

Don't indent verbatim environments: the spaces at the beginning of the lines are not ignored.

[image]

Comment: Your MWE seems to work (thank you!) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to apply to my example. I'll need time to produce a second MWE. The code comes from a (pretty messy) beamer file.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian One more reason not to try to “optimize”. I don't think that in your `beamer` file you have so many listings that such optimization adds to efficiency. To the contrary, it reduces flexibility.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is a request in the specs of a freelance job I'm doing. What else shall I do? :-) hand them a opy of the TeXBook doesn't seem a viable option.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Without an example of the more complex setup where the thing fails, little can be said.